# How to Post Array of Values in Retrofit Android?

Tags: android, retrofit

Using Retrofit i dont know how to pass array of Values. My request look like this

```
{
   type: integer,
   id: string,
   request: {
      country: [ {
         C-id: string,
         C-name: string,
         pin: string },
       ],
}
}
```

I tried like this but i dont have any responses,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(“/sam”)
void multi(@Field("type") int type, @Field("id") String id, @Field("request") ArrayList<Process> processResponses, Callback<Multiplex> cb);
```

Please help me to find solution

Comment: try `@Field("request[]") ArrayList<Process> processResponses`

Answer (score 0):

Create POJO describing your request and use the **@Body** field in retrofit to send the request.

```
@POST("/sam")
void multi(@Body MyRequest requestObject, Callback<Multiplex> cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Set the values in your model class:

```
 @POST(“/sam”)

    void multi(@Body ModelClass modelClass, Callback<Multiplex> cb);
```